# ZNC Broke After Enable TUN/TAP on my VPS

Tags: ssl, irc

After enabling TUN/TAP via my vps and then disabling (causing restarts to server as well), ZNC will no longer work. ZNC won't start on boot, or manually. Here are the errors:

```
[ !! ] Binding to port [+1025] using ipv4... [ SSL is not enabled ]
[ ** ] Unrecoverable config error.
```

Note: Other applications which I have use SSL as well and they still work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message is shown *only* if you compiled ZNC without OpenSSL support. This is not related to TUN/TAP – you probably just compiled a newer version with missing options, then forgot to test it, but it got started on next reboot.

Recompile with `./configure --with-openssl`, and make sure you have the OpenSSL devel headers installed (libssl-dev or such).